# How can I use events with overwritten endpoint methods in spring data rest?

Tags: spring-data-rest

im using spring-data-rest and i am overriding a patch endpoint. Now I have the problem, no events are fired from the @RepositoryEventHandler @HandleAfterSave.
Also I implement myself an AbstractRepositoryEventListener and override the "onAfterSave" method nothing is happen.

If I delete my overriding and use the default patch endpoint from the repository, it is working.
Any idea, how can I get the events with my overwritten patch endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

[RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/main/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) has a method `patchItemResource`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_MAPPING + "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public ResponseEntity<RepresentationModel<?>> patchItemResource(RootResourceInformation resourceInformation,
    PersistentEntityResource payload, @BackendId Serializable id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler,
    ETag eTag, @RequestHeader(value = ACCEPT_HEADER, required = false) String acceptHeader)
    throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, ResourceNotFoundException {

  resourceInformation.verifySupportedMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH, ResourceType.ITEM);

  Object domainObject = payload.getContent();

  eTag.verify(resourceInformation.getPersistentEntity(), domainObject);

  return saveAndReturn(domainObject, resourceInformation.getInvoker(), PATCH, assembler,
      config.returnBodyOnUpdate(acceptHeader));
}
```

The above return statement calls `saveAndReturn`.

```java
private ResponseEntity<RepresentationModel<?>> saveAndReturn(Object domainObject, RepositoryInvoker invoker,
    HttpMethod httpMethod, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, boolean returnBody) {

  publisher.publishEvent(new BeforeSaveEvent(domainObject));
  Object obj = invoker.invokeSave(domainObject);
  publisher.publishEvent(new AfterSaveEvent(obj));

  PersistentEntityResource resource = assembler.toFullResource(obj);
  HttpHeaders headers = headersPreparer.prepareHeaders(Optional.of(resource));

  if (PUT.equals(httpMethod)) {
    addLocationHeader(headers, assembler, obj);
  }

  if (returnBody) {
    return ControllerUtils.toResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK, headers, resource);
  } else {
    return ControllerUtils.toEmptyResponse(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, headers);
  }
}
```

The `BeforeSaveEvent` and `AfterSaveEvent` is published there. The class of `publisher` is `ApplicationEventPublisher`.

So the solution should be `implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware` and publish event with `ApplicationEventPublisher` in your overrided patch endpoint class and method.